# while read, grep, pipes, and hanging

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

```
yes "test" | grep -m3 "test"
```

prints

```
test
test
test
```

and then terminates. So does

```
yes "test" | while read line; do echo $line; done | grep -m3 "test"
```

and

```
yes "test" | while read line; do echo $line; done | grep -E "*" | grep -m3 "test"
```

But

```
yes "test" | while read line; do echo $line | grep -E "*"; done | grep -m3 "test"
```

prints

```
test
test
test
```

and then hangs. What is happening here?

Comment: It's not a `grep` thing, since the same hang can be seen with `yes "test" | while read line; do echo $line | cat; done | head -3`.  Remove the `| cat` and it doesn't hang.

Comment: And if you do `set -x`, you'll see that loop runs far more than 3 times in all cases (probably enough to empty the buffer in the cases where it does die).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In

```
yes "test" | while read line; do echo $line; done | grep -E "*" | grep -m3 "test"
```

there are four processes, running `yes`, the shell program running that `while` loop, `grep`, and `grep` respectively.  The last process in the pipeline terminates, closing the read end of its input pipe, after three matches.  The pipeline then terminates by a chain of `SIGPIPE`s in the usual way for prematurely terminated pipelines, as each stage of the pipline in turn ends up writing to a broken pipe.

In

```
yes "test" | while read line; do echo $line | grep -E "*"; done | grep -m3 "test"
```

there are three processes running `yes`, the shell program, and `grep` respectively.  But the second process along, the one running the shell program, is continually spawning two *further* child processes, one doing the `echo` and one running another `grep` instance.  It is that latter process that gets sent the `SIGPIPE` and *not* the process running the shell program.  It is that latter process that is, after all, actually writing to the broken pipe.

The consequence of this is that the second stage of the pipeline, the shell running that `while` loop, is never *itself* terminated with `SIGPIPE` and just keeps on running, spawning a child pipeline; over and over.  It sees the child pipeline that it spawned terminate with a `SIGPIPE` of course, but for the shell running the `while` loop that is *not* a reason to terminate the loop.